# Summing multiple fields with group returns wrong amount (Rails 6.1)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Here's a sample of the query I'm doing in my rails app

```
sum = Model.group(:insurance_id).sum('payment + additional_payment')
```

However, the `sum` for `insurance_id = 1` returned is wrong compared to if I query for individual `insurances` and do the calculations, i.e.

```
sum_1 = Model.where(insurance_id: 1).sum(:payment)
sum_2 = Model.where(insurance_id: 1).sum(:additional_payment)

sum != (sum_1 + sum_2) # by right, this should be equal?
```

**Other relevant info:**

- `payment` and `additional_payment` are decimal fields with `precision: 10, scale: 2`
- `payment` and `additional_payment` can be `nil` or 0
- the difference of the sums varies up to the thousands digit

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

TIL that adding to `nil` value will return `nil` which is not what I wanted. It should treat the `nil` value as 0. So I simply used `coalesce` like so:

```
sum = Model.group(:insurance_id).sum('coalesce(payment, 0) + coalesce(additional_payment, 0)')
```

And that fixed the problem of summing nullable values. Hope this helps others in the future!

Comment: It's `null` when in SQL-land.